# Passing a route parameter / form data through all controller functions

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, design-patterns

Got a small problem I need help solving out, I'm using laravel version 8.

So I have 3 different databases which have the same tables, I made a model for each database.

So for reference:

- Model `DB1entries` - DB1 - `entries_table`
- Model `DB2entries` - DB2 - `entries_table`
- Model `DB3entries` - DB3 - `entries_table`

So when sending a request i want all requests get to the same controller but the database can be changed depending on the request DB selected, can be with a param on the route.

for example:

- `/db1/store` would go to `EntriesController` and create the entry in DB1
- `/db2/store` would go to `EntriesController` and create the entry in DB2

but the "set" for the model wouldn't be the store function in `EntriesController`.

I just don't want to use the same function to set the model for each function inside the controller, I want to create it dynamically in the constructor or any other solution.

Comment: If you have same tables structure in each DB you could just use same model but with multi DB connections, Laravel offers this features. see this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Answer (score 0):

If that is how you want to define your routes then you could have `/db1/store` or `/db2/store` be a route parameter

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

which would look like `/{db}/store`